# Im expecting a function to return a string but seems to return undefined. it's not passing Mocha test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have a js file where I implement a fetch call to an API, the returned value is indeed a string (or it should be).

I'm trying to run a test that check it is true, but it does not pass the test. Can you tell me where I am making the mistake?

this is my users.js file code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

exports.retrieveFirstUserName = () => {
    let title = "";
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            title = json.title;
            console.log(typeof title);
        });
};
```

And this is the test:

```
var assert = require("chai").assert;
var users = require("./users");

describe("fetching function tests using ASSERT interface from CHAI module: ", function () {
    describe("Check retrieveFirstUserName Function: ", function () {
        it("Check the returned value using: assert.equal(value,'value'): ", function () {
            result = users.retrieveFirstUserName();
            assert.typeOf(result, "string");
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: `retrieveFirstUserName()` does not return anything, so your `result` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Also, since you're doing an asynchronous operation (fetching some JSON from a server) you'll need to return the promise from `retrieveFirstUserName` and then wait for it to resolve in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your function should return its promise:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

exports.retrieveFirstUserName = () => {
    let title = "";
    return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            title = json.title;
            console.log(typeof title);
            return title;
        });
};
```

Then, to test it, you have to wait on the promise and then check.

```
describe("fetching function tests using ASSERT interface from CHAI module: ", function () {
    describe("Check retrieveFirstUserName Function: ", function () {
        it("Check the returned value using: assert.equal(value,'value'): ", function () {
            users.retrieveFirstUserName().then(result => {
                assert.typeOf(result, "string");
            });
        })
    })
})
```